# firefox - how to clear http / https cache?

Tags: http, firefox, browser, https

I've recently completely switched to Firefox Developer Edition but I have a problem I've not been able to handle yet on FF. 
I'm a web developer so it happened to me to have several subdomains which corresponds to a test env of a live website.

exemple : http://local.example.com is my local for https://www.example.com

As it's a common problem to have modules licensed for a domain and its subdomains, I have to process this way to have a correct development environment (with the same modules than the live env).

My problem is the following : if I go to https://www.example.com Firefox will remember that it accessed it in https and will force my local to https://local.example.com instead of http://local.example.com (and of course the https on my local is not configured)

Cleaning the browser cache does not help (it solved the problem on chrome). 
Changing the ttl of the dns to 0 in Firefox config did not help. 
Restarting the browser does not help neither. 
In the developer panel settings, i checked "disable http cache when dev tools is open", it did not worked.

At the moment, I have to work on my local in a private window, which is not very practical.

Does anybody knows how I can flush this cache in Firefox ?

Even better : is there a way to disable this cache ? As I'm using the developer edition, that would be awesome to be able to disable it at least on this version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the root domain seems to affect the other domains, it may seem you are using HSTS to make sure all requests are https.

You have 3 solutions to fix this:

## Exclude subdomains on the main HTST header

The simplest solution for you and all other developers working on your site may be removing the `includeSubDomains` on the HTST header on your main domain. (But beware that this decreases security if you actually use other subdomains)

## Use a private window

HTST domains are not shared by to a private window for privacy reasons

## Get an free SSL certificate for local.example.com

Temporary redirect the global local.example.com domain to your computer, and use letsencrypt to get a certificate for your pc

Comment: OK thanks for your answer. I understand that if I want to do it permanently, there's no other way than what you described. But what if I just want to flush the "domain cache" which contains which protocol my browser have to use for a domain and its subdomain ?

Comment: According to the following resource: https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/919498#answer-311682 you can right click in the history menu on the site, and then forget this site, and if you then open it in a new tab, it should work. But I don't use Firefox on the PC I'm on at the moment, so I couldn't verify the answer

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I'll continue to use private browsing for now and when I'll have some extra time, I'll proabbly generate certificates with lets encrypt. Have a nice day!